# How to send Email from a Batch file?

Tags: email, batch-file

I want the Email and Message in the Code to be sent to my Email "example@gmail.com'. I'm new to coding. Please help me to do this.

```
    @echo off
color a
title Message Me  
echo Instructions: 
echo 1) Type the message and hit ENTER/RETURN

cd "C:\MessageMe"
set /p user=Email ID:
set /p message=Message:
echo Username="%user%" Message="%message%">Sent_Items.txt
echo Press any key to continue
pause >n
echo Loading.....
echo Enter E-Mail Again
set /p user=Email ID:
echo Username="%user%">Confirmed.txt
echo.
echo Press any key to Send
echo.
echo.
pause >
echo.
echo Processing...
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause >n
```

Comment: You should be looking at using powershell. Also this post needs to be moved to the SuperUser site, doesn't belong on SO...

Answer (score 2):

To send Emails from the Windows command-line, you can

- ...forget using raw `telnet.exe` as it cannot accept input from a file
- ...use a `telnet.exe` replacement like [Albert Yale's telnet scripting tool](http://support.moonpoint.com/downloads/windows/network/Telnet/tst10.php)
- ...use an actual command-line Email client like [`blat`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blat/)
- ...use PowerShell, like e.g. this<sup>[1](http://www.howtogeek.com/120011/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-send-email-from-the-command-line-in-windows-without-extra-software/)</sup>:

---

```
$EmailFrom = “yourgmailadress@gmail.com”
$EmailTo = “destination@somedomain.com”
$Subject = “The subject of your email”
$Body = “What do you want your email to say”
$SMTPServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“usr”, “pass”);
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

Comment: Yo! Thanks for this valuable answer.
Honestly. I am a noob to these coding shit.
I would like you to post the whole code here, because I dunno how to use that Albert Yale's tool. So, if you don't mind... Please don't be mad at me...

Comment: Yo! Sincerly, ain't gonna happen. This isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Currently, I'm making an Adware. Using CMD.